# Angular button is always enabled on form

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this very basic form, that I am trying to enable/disable a button on if the form is/isn't filled out. When using this form, the button is always enabled even when I add/remove data in the input fields.

```
<form #activationForm="ngForm">
    <input type="email" ([ngModel])="email" placeholder="{{'activation.email' | translate}}" required>
    <input type="text" ([ngModel])="code" placeholder="{{'activation.code' | translate}}" required>
    <button [disabled]="activationForm.form.invalid" class="button button--success" translate="activation.activate" (click)="activate()"></button>
</form>
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-activation',
    templateUrl: './activation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./activation.component.scss']
})
export class ActivationComponent {
    public email: string = '';
    public code: string = '';
}
```

Why is the button always enabled?

Comment: Could you please share the component's typescript code?

Comment: There isn't anything related to the form in the typescript... Do I need to add TypeScript for this to work?

Comment: I guess the only related javascript thing I have is `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: Too me, looks like the `disabled` property is being bound to an attribute of a property of the component you're rendering:  `activationForm.form.invalid`

Comment: If that property doesn't exist, the `disabled` attribute is not being updated nor bound to any resolved value.

Comment: Assuming `activationForm` is your `FormGroup`, you need `activationForm.invalid` instead

Comment: @mwilson changing it to that gives the same results.

Comment: this `([ngModel])` is wrong and you have to provide a name attribute , check my answer and I have include a demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). There's a cleaner way to do what you want.

Here's an example:

**App Module:**

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [
  ...
  ReactiveFormsModule
]
```

**Component TypeScript:**

```
this.activationForm = new FormGroup({
  email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  code: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
});
```

**Component Template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="activationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
  <input formControlName="email" />
  <input formControlName="code" />
  <button [disabled]="activationForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you're using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/), you can then leverage `mat-hint` or `mat-error` to assist with validation messages/hints. You can also make your own, of course.

The bonus with [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) is that everything is accessible. For example, you can do 'dynamic stuff' with your form by accessing their `FormControl` with `this.activationForm.get('email')`. The same goes for the form itself (ex: `this.activationForm.setValue(...)`). It's pretty powerful and in my opinion, much more preferable than [NgForm](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm).

Comment: I normally don't use template form , reactive form is my way, even for one field form  

Comment: I am currently getting a few errors: `No provider for ControlContainer`,
`Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'` and `No provider for NgControl`

Comment: you need to import this module `ReactiveFormsModule`

Answer (score 2):

to set two way data binding with ngModel it like this `[(ngModel)]="email"` also you have to provide name attribute

```
<form #activationForm="ngForm">
    <input type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="{{'activation.email' }}" required>
    <input type="text" name="code" [(ngModel)]="code" placeholder="{{'activation.code' }}" required>
    <button [disabled]="activationForm.form.invalid" class="button button--success" translate="activation.form.invalid" (click)="activate()">create</button>
</form>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tw5efd)

Comment: This looks like it is working, looks like the primary issues was that I had the `[` and `(` reversed.

Comment: I don't use template form that much but it's always complain about the name attribute , because template form meant to be used without create any property at the component class body I think that why the name attribute is required

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3sswy7